# Self-updating textfield in Pages 6.2

Tags: pages, text

I'm new with using Pages, and testing it for writing a spec for a small software project.

As the spec should be a frequently kept up-to-date document, I would like to have a textfield on the front page that says "Last edited dd.mm". If this text could be made to auto-update, for example on every save or just generally, this would be a major boon.

What I've found so far is that I can insert the current date from the menu - but that does not update the text without selecting it and clicking "Set to today" afaik. An option is to show the revision number, if that is somehow more possible.

The closest thing I could find was [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63650/is-there-a-way-for-pages-to-display-an-auto-updating-date-in-ordinal-format), which said it wasn't possible after 2014, with the latest update in 2016, v.5.6. Is there a way to accomplish this in Pages 6.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution requires **Numbers** but the date changes on opening.

- In Numbers create a single cell table
- Then enter the following formula: `"Last edited: "& DAY(TODAY()) & " : " & MONTH(TODAY())`
- select the table and copy
- in Pages, paste the table in the desired location setting wrap etc.
- format as desired

The day and month will update each time the document is opened.  To see the *last* time it was opened will not be possible unless you use **Quicklook** or get info on macOS.

Be sure to format the data as you wish it to be displayed.

Formulas pasted from Numbers are preserved when pasted into Pages or Keynote. This work-around may be what you need until Apple re-introduces this missing feature.

The example below was made in iOS, but the same applies to macOS.

[image: day month]

Comment: Excellent! Nice to know there is a workaround. Not that pleased with how clumsy it feels to format the table though, but that's probably just practice.

Comment: You are most welcome!  Yeah, a bit clunky, but it can be formatted with some imagination and practice.  I only had my iPad at the time, but the general idea should get you started.  Also, try playing with the `=NOW()` function too.  This also auto updates with the time.

Comment: I implemented this today 24/07/18 by simply typing the formula straight into a table on Pages. It's still clunky if you want the formatting to remain the same as the rest of the document but it works. **The formula I used is just =TODAY**.